# dynamodb query keyConditionExpression sort by sortkey

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to sort my dynamo db results by the sort and key and also get a range of values based on the sort key and i keep getting invalid key condition expression error. basically im trying to get a range of values based on my sort key and also sort them.

example of saved db item:

```
{
id: ORDER_287d6df3-bd9f-472d-87ef-ee9b810b5874
issued_at: 2021-05-07T15:09:11.894Z
base_cur: NGN
orderRate(GSI): SELL#500
quantity: 300
quantityRemaining: 300
quantityRemoved: 0
quote_cur: GBP
rate: 500
side: SELL
ticker(GSI): GBP#NGN
}
```

what i have tried:

```
const params = {
        TableName: process.env.ORDERS_TABLE_NAME,
        IndexName: 'ticker_orderRate',
        KeyConditionExpression: `ticker = :ticker and orderRate between :maxRate and :baseRate`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':ticker': `${quote_cur}#${base_cur}`,
            ':maxRate': `${side === 'BUY' ? 'SELL' : 'BUY'}#${rate}`,
            ':baseRate': `${side === 'BUY' ? 'SELL' : 'BUY'}#0.00`,
        }
    };
```

the rate is a number that comes from an SNS topic.

Error message:

```
ERROR: ValidationException: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: The BETWEEN operator requires upper bound to be greater than or equal to lower bound; lower bound operand: AttributeValue: {S:BUY#620}, upper bound operand: AttributeValue: {S:BUY#0.00}
```

is there a way i can transform the rate and the base rate to numbers while querying the database? and also how do i sort by ascending order?
Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the actual error message you are getting? How are you querying this data (i.e. what is the client)?

Comment: I have added the error message to the question, and im using javascript with the AWS SDK

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your `BETWEEN` clause. As the erorr message states, the upper bound (the second value) must be greater than or equal to the lower bound (the first value).

There are a few things to consider here.

1. Remember, this is a string that you are sorting, not a number. You'll need to make some adjustments to handle that.
2. You need to make sure the length of the number is always the same. This can be accomplished by zero-padding the value (e.g. 1.23 becomes 001.23). Make sure you zero pad to a value that will always be as long or longer than the biggest number you expect.
3. If you support negative values then you need to be explicit on positive values too. Include a plus (`+`) on positive numbers.
4. Dynamically adjust your upper and lower bounds to be in the right order. If the first value is less than the second leave them, if the first value is greater than the second then swap their order.

[Key Condition Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions)

Comment: Could you please explain how i can use a number to sort and or query dynamoDB if it only accepts strings in the keyConditionExpression?

Comment: It doesn't only accept strings. You have chosen a string as your sort key. If your sort key is a number then it will sort as a number.